# Can I build centos 7 (el7) rpm package on centos 6 (el6) server?

Tags: centos, rpm, rpmbuild

There are some documents teaching me on how to build rpm by myself in centos with rpm-build or mock. I am fine to build them for `el6` rpm package.

My question is, can I build a rpm package for centos 7 (el7) on a centos 6 server?

The reason is, my company's build server (a bamboo server) is a centos 6 server currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no:

- Yes, you can do that with Mock. You just run `mock -r epel-7-x86_64 yourpackage.src.rpm` and it will build package for RHEL/CentOS 7 no matter what is your current host.
- No, you cannot do that with rpmbuild as that builds packages for your current platform.

Comment: the second point is not really true: if you set up manually a chroot env with all necessary files from `el7`, then you could build `el7` package for `el7` system. However this is exactly what `mock` does.

Comment: Thanks all. I got the point. `Mock` is the right tool to do the job smoothly with current environment.